# Проблема с AJAX

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Как сделать, этот код, через SetIntrerval, что-бы обращался к файлу раз в  2 секунду?

```
params = "text=sens"
request = new ajaxRequest()
request.open("POST", "send.php", true)

request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length)
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close")

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
        if (this.status == 200) {

            if (this.responseText != null) {
                document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = this.responseText

            }
            else alert("Ошибка ajax Данные не получены")
            document.getElementById('warning').innerHTML = '<p>Ошибка ajax Данные не получены</p>';
        }

        document.getElementById('warning').innerHTML = this.statusText
    }
}
request.send(params)

       function ajaxRequest() {
try {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
}
catch (e1) {
    try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP")
    }
    catch (e2) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        }
        catch (e3) {
            request = false
        }
    }
}
return request
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На `jQuery` так.

```
setInterval(function () {
  $.post('send.php', {text: 'sens'});
}, 2000);
```

Так, на заметку, сравните кол-во кода.

Comment: на мой взгляд, @Zow правильно делает, что учить `native javascript` лишним не будет.

Comment: Я против ничего не имею, предложил вариант.